# Running Ruby on Scotchbox

Tags: ruby, linux, vagrant

I have the latest install of scotchbox for vagrant - https://box.scotch.io/ and it says that I have ruby 2.2 installed, but I don't know how to access it. Ruby doesn't autocomplete at the command line and

```
find / -name ruby
```

comes back with references to ruby inside of

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
```

Is that what I'm supposed to run and type it in manually? Or did something go wrong that it's not accessible as a command?

I'm trying to install [linux homebrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) and I get the error

```
Error: No Ruby found, cannot proceed.
```

When I install it.

Comment: You really shouldn't use Homebrew on Linux; see the discussion at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9346464.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find will return any filename so it does not mean its installed.

to make its installed you can run `which` or the `<program> -version` (most program have a version option to know which version you're running)

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ which ruby
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/ruby
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ ruby -version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

so in this case (scotchbox VM) ruby is installed

however its only installed for vagrant user, if you do the same as root user

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ su -
Password:
root@scotchbox:~# ruby -version
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

you see that ruby is not installed.

To install linuxbrew then, make sure to do the installation as vagrant user. If you're running a provisioning from Vagrantfile make sure to add `privileged: false` so something like

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "<install brew script>"
```